# Make gap size proportional to gap in series data

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm using [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) to draw time series data. Instead of explaining what I'm trying to do, please visit this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqcd8cqw/2/). My problem is the gap between the missing data. If you observe the graph, there are two gaps.
1) For the first gap, data is missing for ~15 mins. From 1:11 AM to 1:30 AM.
2) For second gap data is missing for ~5 hrs. From 2:12 AM - 7:36 AM.

If you observe the gap width stays the same for 15 mins and 5 hrs missing data. For someone just glancing at the graph, this is misleading.
Is there a way make gap width proportional to missing data? One way is to all `null`s between. But maybe there is an out-of-the-box solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make the xAxis not ordinal, it will space the time evenly over the axis.  https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

```
  xAxis: {
    ordinal:false
  },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aqcd8cqw/3/

Comment: Sweet. That is what I was looking for. Thank you.